# Exact word replace in content using Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to replace some content using regular expression. I am able to do that using the following method:

```
EX: """ The search technique is usefull, the search technique is usefull """
old = 'the'
toreplace = "<span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>" +  old + "</span>"
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(old), re.I)
highlighted_txt = re.sub(pattern,toreplace,A,count)

" <span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>the</span> search tech
nique is usefull, <span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>the</s
pan> search technique is usefull "
```

But what I want to do is replace the old word with what is found exactly in the content. Like the second **"The"** should be replaced with

```
<span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>The</span>

" <span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>the</span> search tech
nique is usefull, <span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>The</s
pan> search technique is usefull "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my problem

```
toreplace = "<span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>\g<0></span>"
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `re.sub` you can put `\0` in the replacement string which will be expanded into the match of the search expression. You need to be sure that the `\0` is not interpreted as an octal escape, so it is convenient to use a raw string literal. For example, you can change the third line of your code to

```
toreplace = r"<span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>\0</span>"
```

and you should get the behavior you are looking for.

Since you want to use the entire matched string, you do not need to create any groups in your regular expression. The 0 group is always defined as the entire matched string.

Comment: When i try this i get " <span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>\x00</span> search technique is usefull, <span  class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>\x00<
/span> search technique is usefull "   the word to replace does not appear on the html page

Comment: @Rakesh, do not forget the *r* before the double quote that opens the replacement string. It prevents the usual processing of backslash escapes. In this case, without the *r* the `\0` is interpreted as an octal escape (as mentioned in the answer) which gives the `\x00` characters in the result. Alternatively, you can escape the backslash before the 0 itself and leave it as a normal string.

Comment: The replace string is exactly the same as you have mentioned in the ans but i still get the octal char

Comment: Doing this fixed my problem                                    toreplace = "<span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>\g<0></span>"

Answer (score 0):

Put the keyword inside capturing group.

```
old = '(the)'
```

And use the captured text as replacement (note the `\1`, which denotes the first capturing group):

```
toreplace = r"<span class='highlight' STYLE='background-color:yellow'>\1</span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use backreferences (see http://docs.python.org/library/re.html ), for example:

```
old = 'the (cat|dog|horse)'

replace = '<span>the old \1</span>'
```

will replace "the cat" with "the old cat".

In your case, replace

```
replace = "..." + old + "..."
```

with

```
replace = "..." + '\1' + "..."
```